# Pass a single parameter to a function that expects an iterator range

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, iterator-range

Consider a function that accepts one or more parameters (e.g. file names). In order to make it versatile, it is advantageous to write it for a general iterator range:

```
template<class Iter>
void function(Iter first, Iter last)
{
  // do something
}
```

Now we can invoke it in the following way, independently of how we store the arguments:

```
WhateverContainer container;
function(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
```

For example, the STL relies heavily on this paradigm.

Now, imagine we want to invoke the function with a single argument that is not stored in a container. Of course we can write:

```
const int value = 5;
std::vector<int> vec(1, value);
function(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

But this solution seems clumsy and wasteful to me.

**Question:** Is there a better low-overhead way of creating an iterator-range-compatible representation of a single variable?

Comment: actually I think i misread your example, but anyhow now it is more clear

Comment: out of curiosity: what function that works on a range can you use in a meaningful way on a single element?

Comment: E.g. a function that can process either one or multiple files given by their names might be a use case.

Comment: btw by no means i wanted to imply that there would be no use case for this

Comment: Sure, it's a valid question. Whenever the single elements in the range are changed, applying the function to a single argument might also be interesting.

Comment: @piripiri Not sure if that's the very best design, though, *possibly* better to have that function just operating on one single file and using [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) on ranges. That might *not always* be suitable, but it's at least an alternative always worth considering...

Comment: @Aconcagua Good point, if the arguments are treated separately anyway that is a good alternative.

Comment: @piripiri, If the arguments of a function call are independent, keep in mind that keeping it to a single element at a time allows for things like using parallel algorithms with no extra work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use pointers, for once:

```
function(&value, &value + 1);
```

In generic code, `std::addressof` instead of the unary operator `&` is somewhat safer, depending on your level of paranoia.

You can of course wrap this in an overload for easier use:

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) function (T &&e) {
    auto p = std::addressof(e);
    return function(p, p + 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the advantages of `std::addressof`?

Comment: See my answer [Is there any advantage of using std::addressof() function template instead of using & (address of) operator in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/a/32680218)

Answer (score 13):

You can treat it like an array of one element per [[expr.unary.op]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3):

```
function(&value, &value + 1);
```

> For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), an object that is not an array element whose address is taken in this way is considered to belong to an array with one element of type T.

Comment: Maybe `std::begin(value)`, `std::end(value)` could be modified to return `&value`, `&value + 1` in this case.

Comment: @Lingxi, Perhaps, but it isn't a very common case and would need to detect a single value vs. a container. This can be hard in general. For example, imagine you want to pass a single container.

Answer (score 6):

You can also *overload* your function template `function` for a *single-element range*:

```
template<typename Iter>
void function(Iter first) {
    return function(first, std::next(first)); // calls your original function
}
```

This way, your original function `function` remains compatible with iterator ranges. Note, however, that using this overload with an empty range will result in undefined behavior.

---

For a single element, `value`, you can use the overload above:

```
function(&value); // calls overload
```

Since operator `&` may be overloaded, consider also using `std::addressof` instead of `&`, as already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173862/8012646).

---

For a range consisting of a single element, you can use the overload above as well, which only needs a single iterator instead of an iterator pair:

```
const int value = 5;
std::vector<int> vec(1, value); // single-element collection
function(std::begin(vec)); // <-- calls overload
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do this in two steps:

1. Define a overload of the template function that takes a container, written in terms of the iterator version.
2. Define a proxy class which treats an object reference as an array of size 1.

c++17 example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// proxy object
template<class T>
struct object_as_container
{
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = std::add_const_t<T>;

    object_as_container(value_type& val) : object_(val) {}

    const_iterator begin() const { return std::addressof(object_); }
    iterator begin() { return std::addressof(object_); }

    const_iterator end() const { return std::next(begin()); }
    iterator end() { return std::next(begin()); }

private:
    value_type& object_;
};

// our function in terms of iterators    
template<class Iter> void func(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    while(first != last)
    {
        std::cout << *first++;
    }
}

// our function in terms of containers
template<class Container> void func(Container&& cont)
{
    func(cont.begin(), cont.end());
}

int main()
{
    const int value = 5;
    func(object_as_container(value));
    func(std::vector { 1,2,3,4,5 });
}
```